# Implementing Angular Universal with existing Express Server

Tags: javascript, angular, express, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I have an `Express` server that serves `Angular` app as a static content, but it also does a lot of other things. Now, I want to add `Server-side Rendering` with `Angular Universal`, but that creates new `Express` server that will serve `Angular` app. How can we serve `Angular Universal` with already existing `Express` app? This should be common feature since a lot of projects didn't implement `Angular Universal` from the start, and has to add it in already existing server. It is strange that official `Angular` docs does not say anything about it.

I want to mention that I implemented `Express` server with `JavaScript`, and not `TypeScript`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this, from your existing express application

```
const server = require(`dist/server/main.js`);//file generated by angular universal
const universalApp = server.app();

const server = <your existing express server>;
server.use('/frontappUrl', universalApp);

server.listen(<port>,...);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for you answer. I actually decided not to use Angular Universal because it didn't work since I used "window" object in a lot of places in my app, and Angular Universal can not render "window" object on the server side, so I would lose some features. I implemented "prerender.io" service instead. Either way, I will try your solution  to check if that would work, since I was trying to figure it our how would I use it with existing Express server and since there are nothing in Docs about it, your answer will be helpful to all others that has the same issue, if it is a working solution.

Comment: @NeNaD you can detect browser and server mode in your app and put your window inside an if statement. take a look at this page: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/angular10-isplatformbrowser-function/